# 6 colored balls in 3 numbered boxes

Tags: combinatorics, balls-in-bins

There are six balls, colored red, orange, yellow, green, blue, and purple. There are also 3 boxes, numbered 1, 2, and 3. How many ways are there to put the balls in the boxes, such that each box has at least 1 ball?

I had 2 methods of doing the problem and got different answers.

- Method 1: I pick a ball to put in box 1, then a ball to put in box 2, and a ball to put in box 3. There are $6\cdot5\cdot4$ ways to do that. Then, the three balls can be randomly put in the three boxes, giving $3^3$. Multiplying them together gives $6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3^3=3240$ ways.
- Method 2：I use complementary counting. There are $3^6$ ways to put the distinct balls into the distinct boxes (without any restrictions). Then, I subtract the ways to put the balls into 2 boxes: $3\cdot2^6$ for the $3$ ways to pick the two boxes, and $2^6$ ways to put the balls into the boxes. Then, I add the ways to put the balls into 1 box: $3\cdot1^6$ to pick a box and put all the balls in it. I get $3^6-3\cdot2^6+3\cdot1^6=540$ ways.

Which method, if any, is correct?

Comment: @Arthur. Yes. Sorry, careless. Method 1 obviously involves double counting. $3240>3^6$.

Comment: Note that $3! \times {6\brace 3} = 540.$

Comment: @MarkoRiedel wait it only equals $120$. How did you get the formula?

Comment: @MarkoRiedel you are not einstein, you can explain its reason.

Comment: @BadAtAlgebra Isn't there $3^9$ ways to put the distinct balls in the distinct boxes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second method is correct.

Your first method overcounts. For instance, that method considers the following four to be distinct:

- Put the red ball in box 1, the orange in box 2, and the yellow in box 3. Then put the rest in box 1.
- Put the green ball in box 1, the orange in box 2, and the yellow in box 3. Then put the rest in box 1.
- Put the blue ball in box 1, the orange in box 2, and the yellow in box 3. Then put the rest in box 1.
- Put the purple ball in box 1, the orange in box 2, and the yellow in box 3. Then put the rest in box 1.

But they all result in the same configuration of balls in boxes, so they *shouldn't* be distinct. In fact, it overcounts so much that you find more than $3^6$ ways of doing it.